# Date Conversion returns wrong date when converted into timestamps

Tags: java, angular, typescript

```
dob : any = "15-05-2001";
```

When sending to server it returns the error `Could not read document: Can not construct instance of java.util.Date from String value '15-05-2001': not a valid representation (error: Failed to parse Date value '15-05-2001': Can not parse date \"15-05-2001\": not compatible with any of standard forms (\"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ\", \"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'\", \"EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz\", \"yyyy-MM-dd\"))\n`

In Angular code tried to convert the the date

```
dob = new Date(moment(dob, "DD-mm-yyyy").format("MM-DD-YYYY")).getTime();
```

returns 1581710400000

which returns wrong date, but server accepted the input.

How can I format this date, so that I can send the required date and server accepts same.

Comment: 1581710400000 is pretty much now, so I assume `moment()` is giving you the wrong object (`now` instead of `dob`) for some reason? Or `dob` is overwritten somewhere? Anything else doesn't really make a lot of sense to me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same problem occurred and my solution was i have converted `datetime` into `toLocalString`.

```
var dateTime = new Date();
var sendObj = dateTime.now().toLocalString();
```

**UPDATE:**

```
dob = "15-05-2001";
dob =  new Date(moment(this.dob, "dd-MM-YYYY").format()).getTime();
```

Comment: Tried this solution toLocaleString()......returns same error from server  "Could not read document: Can not construct instance of java.util.Date from String value '15-05-2001': not a valid representation (error: Failed to parse Date value '15-05-2001': Can not parse date \"15-05-2001\": not compatible with any of standard forms (\"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ\", \"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'\", \"EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz\", \"yyyy-MM-dd\"))\n"

Comment: try this one. ```dob = new Date(moment(this.dob, "dd-MM-YYYY").format()).getTime();```

Answer (score 0):

You can create an `Advice` at backend similar to:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class DateAdvice{

@InitBinder
public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder){
binder.regisyerCustomEditor(Date.class, new PropertEditorSupport(){

 public void setAsTest(String text){
  //convert to date from this text.
  setValue(convertToDate(text));
 }
}
}
}
```

With this you can write all possible combinations to parse the date.

Another way is to change your angular date to follow `YYYY-MM-DD` format.